# jQuery validation one field more than another field

Tags: jquery, validation, rules

I want to show an error if the user enters a value lower than/higher than another field. How can i use validation rules to do it? i need txtBetween1 to be 
more than txtLessthanequal. I would also need txtGreaterequal to be more than txtBetween and txtBetween2 so that user may not enter a ridiculous value.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("greaterThan",
        function (value, element, param) {
            var $otherElement = $(param);
            return parseInt(value, 10) > parseInt($otherElement.val(), 10);
        });

    $("#currencyform").validate({
        messages: {
            txtFrom: "Currency value is required",
            txtTo: "Currency value is required",
            txtConversionRate: "Rate must be a number",
            txtGreaterEqual: "Rate must be more than between",
            txtBetween: "Rate must be number",
            txtBetween1: "Rate must be number",
            txtLessthanEqual: "Rate must be less than between",
        },
        rules: {
            txtConversionRate: {
                min: 1

            },
            txtGreaterEqual: {
                min: 
            },
            txtBetween: {
                min: 1
            },
            txtBetween1: {
                min: 1,
                greaterThan: "#LessthanEqual"
            },
            txtLessthanEqual: {
                min: 1
            },
        },
        focusInvalid: false,
        submitHandler: function () {
            return false;
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().after());
        },
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the user enter the value in textbox1. Suppose in textbox2 you do not want him to enter value greater than the value in textbox1.

What you could do is, create a jquery `onKeyUp()` event for the textbox2, and inside that function get the value of textbox1 every time the function is called. Compare the value and react accordingly if the value is greater than the value in textbox1.

Comment: How do i go about using onKeyUp() ?

Comment: Refer this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_keydown_keyup